# Angular 2 AND Karma Test AND Async HTTP

Tags: http, testing, asynchronous, angular, karma-jasmine

so my problem is very easy to explain

this is my test spec

```
import {
  describe,
  expect,
  it,
  inject,
  beforeEachProviders
} from 'angular2/testing_internal';
import {RestClient} from './rest.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';
import {
  HTTP_PROVIDERS
} from 'angular2/http';
export function main() {
   describe('RestClient Service', () => {
      beforeEachProviders( () => [HTTP_PROVIDERS, RestClient] );
      it('is defined', inject( [RestClient], (client) =>{
         client.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
         .delay(2000)
         .toPromise()
         .then((res) => {
            console.log('test');
            expect(res.length).toBeGreaterThan(1000);
         });
       }));
    });
  }
```

and this is the method in the "RestClient" class that return an Observable

```
public get(url:string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
}
```

So, i start the test and the test return

```
START:
LOG: 'ciao'
RestClient Service
    ✔ is defined
PhantomJS 2.0.0 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) LOG: 'ciao'

Finished in 0.026 secs / 0.038 secs

SUMMARY:
   ✔ 2 tests completed
```

For Karma all work well and the test is passed correctly and is not true, and at the same time if i put a console.log into the "then" never is called.
Som i suppose that is a problem with Async calls, do you have any idea howto test in Angular2 Async Calls
i have used Inject and AsyncInject too.
I know that i can use a MockBackend but i need to test with external urls

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: would you like to post your workaround this problem ? @cingusoft

Answer (score 0):

`injectAsync` should solve your problem, but you need to return the promise:

```
it('is defined', injectAsync( [RestClient], (client) =>{
  return client.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
  .delay(2000)
  .toPromise()
  .then((res) => {
     console.log('test');
     expect(res.length).toBeGreaterThan(1000);
  });
}));
```

Comment: Hi @cexbrayat
thank you for your answer, but i have tested injectAsync as well and still fail.
the test script don't wait the promise and have no $q methods with defer that permit to "stop" the process until the promise complete the loop.

Comment: Which Angular version are you using? It should be waiting for the promise if you are with a recent enough release (like beta.0 or beta.1).

Comment: the version is beta.1 but i found a solution
It's mandatory to inject AsyncTestCompleter like that:

    `it('is defined', injectAsync( [AsyncTestCompleter, RestClient], (async: AsyncTestCompleter, client: RestClient) => {
      client.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').then((res) => {
        console.log('ciaccia');
        expect(res.length).toBeGreaterThan(3);
        async.done();
      });

    }));`
But now i have a problem with JASMINE TIMEOUT, i will investigate

Comment: `AsyncTestCompleter` should probably not be used as it is in the internal API (AFAIK). You may have encounter a bug with your use case because I've got several hundred tests using injectAsync that runs perfectly well. Maybe you should try to open an issue on the official tracker.

Comment: The official testing API (the public one) is `angular/testing`.